# how to disable eslint popups in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, popup, eslint

I don't want to suppress errors, I just want to get rid of this annoying popup that occurs with every one of them. Underlining and showing output errors is fine, but this popup doesn't seem to have a setting in the eslint preferences for hiding.

[image: eslint popup]

Anyone know how to prevent this?